# IP compression for database storage

Tags: java, compression, ip

I have a database that stores the IP number of all users that have used a feature (ie: voted on a poll), and I want to avoid the same user or IP from voting twice.

As a result I have been storing all the IPs of the anonymous users that have voted on my polls. My database is filled with IPs like 123.456.789...

However, that is inefficient, is there a one way function that compresses and IP into a shorter string?

like 123.456.798 => %dA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For IPv4 you can compress an IP address into an `int` like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(ip).useDelimiter("\\.");
int value = (scanner.nextInt() << 24) | (scanner.nextInt() << 16)
        | (scanner.nextInt() << 8) | scanner.nextInt();
```

This can be reversed too:

```
String ip = ((value >> 24) & 0xFF) + "." + ((value >> 16) & 0xFF)
        + "." + ((value >> 8) & 0xFF) + "." + (value & 0xFF);
```

Comment: @Mohamed: yeah it's reversible. I'll update the answer with the reverse code.

Answer (score 2):

If you're storing them as strings in your database, yes that's going to be wasteful. You can convert them into 4 byte integers before you store them.

The class java.net.InetAddress has a getByName method that will return a new InetAddress object. Calling getAddress on the returned object gets you a byte array of the address, which you can turn into an int easily enough.

Note that InetAddress will also work with IPv6 addresses, so you'll want to either make sure you can store those in your DB, or check the type of InetAddress returned from the getByName call to make sure it's an IPv4 address.

Answer (score 1):

An IPv4 address is 32 bits. In dotted notation you have a string of up to 15 bytes that still represents a 32-bit (4-byte) address. The obvious step would be to convert them to binary format, such as with `inet_aton` or `inet_pton`. The latter is generally recommended for new code, since it handles IPv6 addresses in addition to IPv4.

If you need to go beyond that, you *might* try storing the addresses in a trie. That doesn't fit your normal database model very well though, so unless you really have a *lot* or anonymous users, it <strike>may not be</strike> probably isn't worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you aren't supporting IPv6, an ip address fits in an int. You really need something smaller?

And if you are supporting IPv6, two longs will do. Still seems pretty small.

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed something. How do you translate an IPv4 to an int, or a IPv6 to two ints?  I am thinking something like 2 bytes

Comment: @somid - you can't put 4 bytes of data in a 2 byte pail.